# Malformed array literal: "1" error when updating column in postgres sequelize migration script

Tags: node.js, postgresql, types, sequelize.js, jsonb

I am trying to update the column property 'type' of my table 'myTable'.

I know the type `Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSONB)` is supported in Postgres, so I wanted to try it.

So, I updated my migration to the ff.

At first, I tried the simple way of updating column property 'type' to

```
return Promise.all([
  queryInterface.changeColumn("MyTable", "column1", {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)
  })
])
```

But it gives error:

> ```
> column **"column1" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb[]
> ```

So I tried the different approach:

```
return Promise.all([
  queryInterface.changeColumn("MyTable", "column1", {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSONB) + 'USING CAST("data" as ' + Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSONB) + ')'
  })
])
```

But instead it gives error:

> ```
> malformed array literal: "1"
> ```

I just want to update the 'type' of my column but this giving me so much headache.

The Postgres and Sequelize versions are:

```
"pg": "^8.6.0",
"sequelize": "^6.6.2",
```

Any idea on how to fix this one?

Comment: I doubt `"pg": "^8.6.0",` is the Postgres version, as there was no 8.6 Postgres.  I'm guessing that is the driver version. Please update question to include correct Postgres version. Also add to question:  1) What is the actual current type for the column? 2) An example of the current data in the column.

Answer (score 0):

The first error because there is no registered cast from your mysterious, undeclared former column type to `jsonb[]` (array of `jsonb`). (I assume `varchar` or `text`?)

The second error because all existing values in the column must be legal array literals to be cast to `jsonb[]`. Valid example:

```
{"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}","{\"baz\": \"bam\"}"}
```

`jsonb[]` is a very odd choice for a data type.
Are you sure you don't rather want a plain text array (`text[]`) or just `jsonb` *containing* a JSON array?